# why how can i fix the error: variable XX not found with hydrogen and codegen?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, shopify-hydrogen

I am very new to hydrogen / react in general.

I am playing around with hydrogen 2 and the base app they install when setting up a site.

Playing around with the `($locale).products.$handle.jsx` file I have created an extension to the product query which grabs a few new meta fields.

I then import that variable into the file and use it within the query.

The query works totally fine, but the console is giving me the following

[image]

Is there a way to void this error?

This is the query that I am adjusting

```js
const PRODUCT_FRAGMENT = `#graphql
  fragment Product on Product {
    id
    title
    vendor
    handle
    descriptionHtml
    description
    options {
      name
      values
    }
    selectedVariant: variantBySelectedOptions(selectedOptions: $selectedOptions) {
      ...ProductVariant
    }
    variants(first: 1) {
      nodes {
        ...ProductVariant
      }
    }
    seo {
      description
      title
    }
    ${PRODUCT_META_FIELDS}
  }
  ${PRODUCT_VARIANT_FRAGMENT}
`;
```

And the import is just this
`import {PRODUCT_META_FIELDS} from "~/schema/meta-fields";`

So the question is, how do i get rid of the error?
What is the actual preferred way of reusable queries like this?

thanks!